# Documenting user created type declarations with Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx

I'm making a type declaration. For example:

```
from typing import Tuple
Type1 = Tuple[str, float]
```

I would like Sphinx to document this declaration like a function declaration. How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

If I bilded documentation and add usual description the result is that the declaration of these types is displayed as a plain text, not something special.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A canonical Python way is to use `TypeAlias` from [PEP-653](https://peps.python.org/pep-0613/):

```py
#: Funny type that is mixing strings and floats - sounds like JavaScript programming!
Type1: TypeAlias = Tuple[str, float]
```

It was added in Python 3.10.

As the writing of this, Sphinx component that does autogenerated documentation, autodoc, [does not support TypeAlias yet](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/8934).